# Using GroovyClassLoader from Java - Classes not GC'd

Tags: java, memory-leaks, groovy, classloader

I have created a custom Class in java that I am using to custom load Groovy classes.

My Java class starts like this:

```
public class ClassLoader {
    private GroovyClassLoader groovyClassLoader = new GroovyClassLoader();
```

Then I have a method that uses the `groovyClassLoader` to load classes by name:

```
Class c = groovyClassLoader.loadClass(className, true, false, true);
```

This is all working fine, no problems. However, I occasionally want to reload all my Groovy classes dynamically, so at the moment my java code just basically re-instantiates my `ClassLoader` instance. This leaves no remaining reference to the `ClassLoader` instance, and that is GC'd as you would expect.

However, if I examine the loaded classes (using VisualVM and MAT) after reloading a few times I see the Java class `ClassLoader` loaded just once, with just one instance, but there are several instances of `GroovyClassLoader$InnerLoader` (in this case, class loaded once, but several instances) and several classes loaded for `GroovyClassLoader` (like `GroovyClassLoader$1`, `GroovyClassLoader$2`, etc)

Any ideas why despite the Java `ClassLoader` being collected, the `GroovyClassLoader` and its InnerLoader is not being collected?

Thanks!

Comment: `ClassLoader` is a rather poor choice of name for your main Java class here, you would do better to pick a name that doesn't clash with a class in `java.lang`

Comment: perm gen would only be cleaned up while fullgc. use VisualVM fire some and check again. some gc ,for example CMS, would not unload classes without -XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled

Comment: @IanRoberts yes, good point - have been caught out by this before. Will update

Comment: @farmer1992 - yep, thanks , have GC working ok with those flags ensuring perm gen is swept (collects other non-groovy classes)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe there are still some reachable objects that are instances of one of the classes `c` that you loaded by name?  Every class holds a reference to its defining classloader so the classloader can't be GCd until all instances of all classes it loaded have themselves become unreachable.

If this is not sufficient, then it may be the Groovy MetaClass mechanism that is the problem.  You may need to remove your classes explicitly from the `MetaClassRegistry` when you have finished with your `com.example.ClassLoader` instance:

```
public void destroy() {
  for(Class<?> c : groovyClassLoader.getLoadedClasses()) {
    GroovySystem.getMetaClassRegistry().removeMetaClass(c);
  }
}
```

I would have expected Groovy to do this for you but you may need to be more proactive than it wants to be by default.

Answer (score 1):

From my recent experience with Groovy template engine in Play framework, Groovy does not clean the Meta Class Registry when its compiled classes are not reachable from application code.

https://hoangx281283.wordpress.com/2014/07/24/unload-groovy-classes/