# Compiled Groovy Classes - GC

Tags: java, memory-leaks, groovy, garbage-collection

This is a follow on to a previous question: [Using GroovyClassLoader from Java - Classes not GC'd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14343393/using-groovyclassloader-from-java-classes-not-gcd)

I was previously loading Groovy classes in a java environment using a custom groovy classloader, and to get them GC'd correctly I had to explicitly clear the meta class registry as so:

```
for(Class<?> c : groovyClassLoader.getLoadedClasses()) {
    GroovySystem.getMetaClassRegistry().removeMetaClass(c);
}
```

I have now switched to pre-compiling the groovy classes in to a JAR that I am loading via a normal java classloader, and am now seeing the perm gen memory leaks again when I try to re-load the updated classes.

Anyone know if i need to do anything special to get my classes GC'd?  I am dynamically adding constructor/methods to some of the groovy at runtime, so assume I still need to clear the metaClassRegistry?

The above code does not work (obviously) as I am no longer using a groovyClassLoader, but I have also tried just iterating the metaClassRegistry and that just returns null for the registry:

```
    def metaClasses = GroovySystem.getMetaClassRegistry().iterator()
    while( metaClasses.hasNext()){
        def thisGuy = metaClasses.next()
        GroovySystem.getMetaClassRegistry().removeMetaClass(thisGuy)
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was the same problem, but just needed a different route to get to the MetaClassRegistry. The following code did the job:

```
def registry = metaClass.getRegistry()
def iterator = registry.iterator()
while ( iterator.hasNext() ){
    def mc = iterator.next()
    registry.removeMetaClass( mc.getJavaClass() )
}
```

(note, this is called from one of the compiled groovy classes so is using the same classloader/metaClassRegistry)